# Is there a reason I can't add a UIView between a Navigation Bar and a Table View?

Tags: interface-builder

I have a view controller that has a navigation bar and a Table View. Is there a reason why I can't add another View between them using the interface builder to add some labels? I watched a video on youtube that talks about the header and footer delegate methods but when I used that, it replaced the navigation bar with the Rect it had me create.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    final let url = URL(string: "http://www.mildvariety.com/students")

    private var students = [Student]()
    private var selection = ""




    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.delegate = self

//        let headerView = UIView()
//        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
//        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
//        myTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView


        self.loadJson(filename: "students")

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "selection"), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
            let popupVc = notification.object as! SortPopupViewController
            self.selection = popupVc.optionSelected
            print(self.selection)
            self.loadJson(filename: "students")
        }


    }




    func loadJson(filename fileName: String) {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let downloadedStudents = try decoder.decode([Student].self, from: data)
//                print(jsonData[0].firstName)



                self.students = downloadedStudents

                if (self.selection == "firstName") {
                    self.students = students.sorted{$0.firstName < $1.firstName}
                }
                if (self.selection == "lastName") {
                    self.students = students.sorted{$0.lastName < $1.lastName}
                }
                if (self.selection == "year") {
                    self.students = students.sorted{$0.year < $1.year}
                }
                if (self.selection == "gpa") {
                    self.students = students.sorted{$0.gpa < $1.gpa}
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myTableView.reloadData()
                }


            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return students.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StudentCell") as? StudentCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.firstNameLabel.text = students[indexPath.row].firstName
        cell.lastNameLabel.text = students[indexPath.row].lastName
        cell.yearLabel.text = students[indexPath.row].year

        let gpaString:String = String(format:"%.1f", students[indexPath.row].gpa)

        cell.gpaLabel.text = gpaString

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share you code ?

Comment: @Jack Okay It's up. I have a Student Cell and Student model that you probably don't need but I can put them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **one** view above the prototype cell (it becomes the header), and **one** view below (becomes the footer).

You already have a Navigation Bar (which is a view) above the prototype... which is why you can only add your new view below it.

It is rather odd to be adding a Navigation Bar as the table header view. You probably want the View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I must have missed that bit of info in the training.